# Using the Law of the Mean (MVT) to prove the inequality $\log(1+x)<x$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms

If $x \gt0$, then $\log(1+x) \lt x$.

My attempt at the proof thus far...

Let $f(x) = x-\log(1+x)$, then $f'(x) = 1-\frac{1}{1+x}$ for some $\mu \in (0,x)$ (since $x>0$)

MVT give us $f(x) = f(a) + f'(\mu)(x-a)$

So plug in our values we get:

$$x-\log(1+x) = 0+(1-\frac{1}{1+\mu})(x-0)$$

which we can reduce to

$$\log(1+x)=\frac{x}{1+\mu}$$

Now For $x\leq1$, then $0\lt\mu\lt1$

S0 $0\lt \frac{1}{1+\mu}\lt 1$, thus $\log(1+x)\lt x$

If $x>1$, then....

So I can see clearly that if $x>1$ is plugged into $\frac{x}{1+\mu}$

then $\log(1+x)<x$, but I am not sure of how to prove this.

I would appreciate tips hints or proof completions.

Comment: Don't take $x$ to the other side. You want the result $f > 0$, and you showed that $f(x) = \frac{\mu}{1+\mu} x$ for $x>0$, and some $\mu \in (0,x)$. It's easy to see that the RHS is positive.

Comment: perhaps just use that $1-\frac1{1+x}=\frac{x}{1+x}$ is positive for $x>0$.

Comment: Why do I want $f>0$ ?

Comment: Is it because of my inequality  $\log(1+x) \lt x$ then I just move it over to get $0\lt x - \log(1+x)$ and by construction this $x - \log(1+x)$ is my $f$

Comment: TeX remark: use `\log` to type $\log$

Comment: For a simple derivation apply the MVT to $f(x) = \log(1+x)$ then $\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = f'(c) = \frac{1}{1+c} \leq 1$ since $1+c$ is greater than $1$.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Have a look at your statement $$\log(1 + x) = \frac{x}{1+\mu}.$$
No matter what $\mu$ is, $1 + \mu$ is bigger than $1$, hence $$\frac{1}{1+\mu} < 1.$$
Multiplying this final inequality through by $x$ gives you the result you want. In words, dividing $x$ by something bigger than $1$ gives you something smaller than $x$.